# Vouloir "se rencontrer avec qqn", est-ce un cas méritant l'analyse par un psy ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, verbes

Les acceptions du verbe "rencontrer" sont bien fascinantes en français, quand on s'y penche de plus près...

Ainsi, "rencontrer" peut vouloir dire "faire connaissance" (là-dessus, tout le monde est d'accord), "croiser sur son chemin" ("rencontré trois capitaines avec mes sabots dondaines..."), "(re)voir quelqu'un que l'on connaît déjà" (Comme dans "je le rencontre demain", on peut bien dire que "le" se réfère à quelqu'un que l'on connaît déjà).

Tout va bien jusque là... Mais il y a aussi le verbe "se rencontrer". Les grands esprits se rencontrent, c'est bien ! Mais est-ce qu'une phrase comme "il se rencontre avec ses amis" est possible en français ? Plusieurs français natifs déjà interrogés sur ce sujet n'ont pas pu donner une réponse définitive sur le champ...
L'imaginaire linguistique fait qu'au quotidien seules les variantes "il voit ses amis" et "il rencontre ses amis" sont utilisées. Sinon, il faut dire "tous (ses amis et lui-même) se rencontrent".

A mon avis, "se rencontrer" ne se combine pas avec un complément d'objet introduit par la préposition "avec" (sauf pour l'acception "se rencontrer avec" = observer une convergence d'opinions).

Ai-je tort ?

Merci !

Comment: Just a thought, probably wrong, but if the subject is plural/compound & the primary focus of the meeting is between the people making up the subject, then PERHAPS “avec” could be used to introduce a third party who is present but not a true party to the official “rencontre”: "Les 2 boxeurs se sont rencontrés avec l’arbitre [à côté]" or "Nathalie et Paul se rencontrent une dernière fois comme fiancés à l’autel avec le pasteur."  & there’s the following, which probably falls in the “observer une convergence d'opinions” exception that you mention: "Ils se rencontrent avec l’idée de réconcilier."

Comment: Thanks for your comment and it's true about the last two examples in which "avec" is followed by the object other than a person or living creature, or "avec le pasteur" looks like addition to the main meaningful part of the utterance.

Comment: "se rencontrer avec" sounds pretty much like something a Chinese-native speaker learning French would say, because Chinese verbs often need an object specified with a particle, and 和 is translated in French by both "et" and "avec" (and probably other). On the other hand, French verbs aiming at somebody more rarely need a preposition: "aider {} quelqu'un", "rencontrer {} quelqu'un"...

Answer (score 7):

Selon moi vous avez raison dans le cas général. Il faudrait dire "il rencontre ses amis", ou alors si l'on veut utiliser se rencontrer, dire "ils se rencontrent entre amis", ou encore comme vous l'avez mentionné: ses amis et lui se rencontrent.

Par contre voici un cas de figure qui s'éloigne un peu de votre opinion. Supposons que nous essayons de réconcilier deux personnes qui ne s'entendent plus. Il pourrait arriver que nous essayons de les faire se rencontrer. Ils pourraient se rencontrer difficilement, et si j'en faisais le rapport je pourrais dire *qu'ils se sont rencontrés **avec** difficulté*. Et dans la forme présente cela donnerait: ***ils se rencontrent avec difficulté***. Je n'ai pas exploré le point davantage mais j'aurais tendance à penser qu'il y aurait d'autres cas de figure similaires.

Comment: Merci pour ce commentaire. En effet, les cas comme "se rencontrer avec difficulté" sont possible parce que "avec difficulté" est substituable par "difficilement". 
Mais alors est-ce qu'on peut "se rencontrer avec un problème", "se rencontrer avec un obstacle" ? A mon avis, c'est non :)

Answer (score 2):

In very informal speaking, I think I could say something along the lines of

> Ils se rencontrent avec des amis

(especially in Quebec) or, if I'm talking about an habit, something like that is definitely acceptable :

> Ils se rencontrent avec les autres chaque semaine

Answer (score 1):

La question est pointilleuse et même pour un français natif, elle suggère une une réflexion appuyée sur l'utilisation de *« se rencontrer »*.

La phrase *« il se rencontre avec ses amis »* peut être employée, elle est correcte et juste. Mais à l'usage, il faut mieux remplacer le verbe se rencontrer par *« se voir »* ou *« se trouver »* et *« se réunir »*.

Comment: This reply is incorrect. The plural is mandatory with *se rencontrer* and *se voir* which require reciprocity; i.e. *ses amis* are included in the subject. Singular is fine with *se trouve* and *se réunit* which can apply to the subject *il* only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are just correct: 
"se rencontrer avec + forme adverbiale" is OK, but 
"se rencontrer avec + objet/personne" is KO.

If you say "Ils rencontrent. / They meet." (incorrect in French), the question is what or who do they meet – though here it will be implied in English.

To say "They meet themselves", you'll say "Ils ***se*** rencontrent." (correct, necessary).

But then, you cannot say "They meet themselves *with Paul*.", at least in French, "Ils se rencontrent avec Paul." (incorrect). It's counter intuitive, since ***se*** already tells who they meet – themselves, each other.
Here "se" is called a reflexive pronoun (pronom réfléchi), it makes the subject also the object like in "Je ***me*** douche. / I shower myslef.".

So yes, if you try to meet yourself with someone, he's probably a shrink. :-) 
"Me rencontrer avec quelqu'un." would then mean "with someone's help / avec *l'aide de* quelqu'un". But can't be "to meet myself *and* somebody else". This "avec quelqu'un" looks like an object but it's a mean, a circumstance.

But you cannot say "The bride and groom meet themselves with the priest. / La fiancée et le fiancé se rencontrent avec le prêtre." (incorrect).

What you can say is that they meet "in front of the priest / Ils se rencontrent devant le prêtre." (correct)

Of course, they still can meet themselves with joy ("with joy" being adverbial, not Joy the fristname): "Ils se rencontrent avec joie." (correct)

Or with whatever condition: "Ils se rencontrent avec de grandes difficultés." (correct)

There is probably a confusion, even for some natives, with "se retrouver avec un chat / des amis / une surprise", which is very similar, but grammatically different.  
"Des amis ***se*** retrouvent ***avec*** d'autres amis." (correct) and mostly equivalent to  
"Des amis retrouvent d'autres amis." (correct)

Note that in Spanish you do use such a form "*encontrar**se con** alguien*", but it's not French.